# Django REST giving a 403 forbidden on DELETE methods, but not POST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to delete an entry using an ajax call.
when I am using the default 'delete' method from `generics.DestroyAPIView`, I am getting a 403 Forbidden, but if I add a post method, call the delete method immediately and change the ajax type to 'post' it works fine. Would anyone have an idea what causes this?

Note that I overwrite the get_object function to get the object based on posted data. (could it be due to delete methods not allowing to post data? If so, why? And how would you pass the CSRF token??)

ajax:

```
      $.ajax({
        url: '{% url "account:api:post_details_delete" %}',
        type: 'delete',
        data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}", name: json.name, value: json.value }
      });
```

url:

```
path('post_details/delete/', PostDetailDeleteApiView.as_view(), name='post_details_delete'),
```

view:

```
class PostDetailDeleteApiView(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostDetailSerializer

    # the code below allows it to work if uncommented and type in ajax changed to 'post'
    # def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #   return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_object(self):
        """
        Returns the post detail object to be deleted based on the name:value pair
        provided by the ajax call.
        """
        data = self.request.data
        obj = Post_Detail.objects.filter(
            name=data.get('name', ''), value=data.get('value', '')
        ).filter(
            post__account__user=self.request.user
        )
        if obj.exists():
            return obj.get()
        else:
            raise Http404
```

serializer:

```
class PostDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post_Detail
        fields = ['name', 'value']
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same issue - neither POST nor DELETE are working over AJAX but if I call it via the browsable API it works

Answer (score 1):

A 403 Forbidden error code would suggest that in some way or another that either permission is denied or that you're not authenticated.

The 'DestroyAPIView' is used for delete-only API endpoints for a single model instance.

Do you have the full traceback that you can append to your question?

**Docs References**

[Django REST Framework's Destroy API View](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#destroyapiview)

[Django REST Framework's Guide to Permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)

Comment: Well, the only error I am getting is in the console: "Forbidden: /my/api/path/" and from chrome console: "Status Code: 403 Forbidden". Note that I can freely delete the entry through the Django REST browsable API, so my Permissions are fine and it seems like I've configured the API View correctly as well (since it works fine through the browsable API.) The issue starts when I make ajax calls to the same API. Again; if I change the type to "POST" from "DELETE" and change the view's POST function to just call the DELETE function; then my ajax calls work just fine.

Comment: OK, taking a look at your urls.py file, it seems as though your url isn't targeting the one detail view. A detail view is usually identified by either an ID/PK (primary key), a slug or a UUID field.

Comment: Also, I just scanned the ajax code and I note the brackets do not exactly match. At the very end, there seems to be an extra closing curly brace.

Comment: I do not include the pk/id in the url as the object to be deleted is identified by the unique combination of `value`, `name` (provided in the 'data' attribute of the ajax call) and the current user. The combination of those 3 narrows down the object to be deleted to a single object (this is done in the 'get_object' method in the view).

Comment: Oh and the extra bracket in the ajax call is a copy/paste error on my part as the ajax call is inside a function in my code, I accidentally included the closing bracket of the javascript function (which I haven't included in the snippet to make it simpler). Good observation though :) Thank you.      Would you have any other suggestions? Note that the code works fine if I simply change the type to `post` instead of `delete`, so seems like the logic is correct.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/) you must pass the csrftoken to headers of ajax request

> While the above method can be used for AJAX POST requests, it has some inconveniences: you have to remember to pass the CSRF token in as POST data with every POST request. For this reason, there is an alternative method: on each XMLHttpRequest, set a custom X-CSRFToken header (as specified by the CSRF_HEADER_NAME setting) to the value of the CSRF token. This is often easier because many JavaScript frameworks provide hooks that allow headers to be set on every request.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue while passing DELETE calls over AJAX to my API endpoint. POST calls worked just fine but DELETE calls would get blocked with a 403.

To solve this, you must pass an additional header with the AJAX call that includes the CSRF token.

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/delete/15',
     headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': {{ csrf_token }} },
     type: 'DELETE',
     success: function(result) {
         // Do something with the result
     }
});
```

The DRF documentation calls this out here - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#csrf-protection

And Django documentation provides guidance on how to set the header here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax